# Como pegar a sua própria localização (LatLng) no Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

Preciso setar no meu mapa a minha própria localização para criar calcular a rota de onde estou até o ponto que quero chegar. Eu consigo criar um marcador para o destino, mas não sei como solicitar ao android minha propiá localização e marcar no mapa.

Sei que nescessita do `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` mas sem o `LatLng` não consigo posicionar ou marcar no mapa.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você já está utilizando o google play services e já conectou (exemplo abaixo):

```
 if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .build();
 }
 if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
 }
```

Agora é só:

```
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    myLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (myLocation != null) {
       latText.setText(String.valueOf(myLocation.getLatitude()));

       longText.setText(String.valueOf(myLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
  }
```

Inclusive, na documentação tem o exemplo de como pegar sua própria localização também: [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: Estou usando o Play service:11.8.0.
Mas quando escrevo o LocationServices ele não reconhece